# How can I extract the email address string

Tags: python

My python script currently pulls an email address as a list, but I need to get the text portion only. In this example, it should have been golfshop@3lakesgolf.com. I have tried using the text attribute (gc_email.text), but that didn't work.

```
gc_email=web.select('a[href^=mailto]')
print(gc_email)
```

output:

```
[<a href="mailto:golfshop@3lakesgolf.com">golfshop@3lakesgolf.com</a>]
```

Help! How can I extract just the mailto address?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex capture to pull this string

```
import re

str = '<a href="mailto:golfshop@3lakesgolf.com">golfshop@3lakesgolf.com</a>'
regex = '<a href="mailto:(.*?)".*'

try:
    match = re.match(regex, str).group(1)
except:
    match = None
    x=1

if match is not None:
    print(match)
```

Output

```
golfshop@3lakesgolf.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Only thing is the parenthesis denoting the data to be a list vs str. For some reason, having problems with converting from list to str.

Comment: You need to pull the strings out of the array prior to preforming the regex. Are you working with an array of strings that will all contain valid email addresses within them?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every line follows the format you provided, you could use the '.split()' function on a series of characters and then select the appropriate items from the returned lists.

```
line = '<a href="mailto:golfshop@3lakesgolf.com">golfshop@3lakesgolf.com</a>]'
sections1 = line.split(':')
email = sections1[1].split('.com')[0]+'.com'
```

Output

```
golfshop@3lakesgolf.com
```

If the formatting varies and is not like this every single time, then I'd go with regular expressions.